# AWS cloudwatch logs search by string using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I am able to get the aws logs using below code, but i am trying to find a way to search by string, in my case it is guid (request-id), is there a way to pass the string as part of search itself ? as i see in AWS console UI there is option to search

Note: i understand i can filter the logs after getting the logs results in Java

```
        FilterLogEventsRequest filterLogEventsRequest = FilterLogEventsRequest.builder()
                .logGroupName(logGroupName)
                .logStreamNames(logStreamName)
                .limit(100)
                .startTime(startTime)
                .build();
```

Comment: Does one of the methods in the Javadoc do what you want https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/model/FilterLogEventsRequest.html specifically `setFilterPattern` as shown here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html

Comment: Yes, it worked, it was not working earlier as i missed to add escape characters for special characters like "-" thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you sorifiend, using filterPattern worked fine.

```
                FilterLogEventsRequest filterLogEventsRequest = FilterLogEventsRequest.builder()
                        .logGroupName(logGroupName)
                        .logStreamNames(logStreamBatch)
                        .limit(LOG_FILTER_BATCH_SIZE)
                        .startTime(startTime)
                        .nextToken(nextToken)
                        .filterPattern(filterPattern)
                        .build();
```