Writing java code for filtering logs from cloudwatch log group
I am testing java code for filtering cloudwatch log group with following query:
Can someone help me with syntax because I get error InvalidParameterException: Invalid character(s) in term '@'?
this is query from aws:
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log 
| sort @timestamp desc 
| filter @message like "A_B" 
| parse @message "\"userInfo\":\"*\"" as userInfo 
| stats count(*) by userInfo

how to write this query in java?
ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();
AWSLogsClientBuilder builder = AWSLogsClientBuilder.standard();
AWSLogs logsClient = builder.withCredentials( new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider( new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials() ) )
.withRegion( Regions.US_EAST_1 )
.withClientConfiguration( clientConfig ).build();  

FilterLogEventsRequest request = new FilterLogEventsRequest()
.withLogGroupName(logGroupName)
.withLogStreamNames(logStreamName)
.withFilterPattern(queryString)
.withStartTime(firstDateTimestamp.toEpochMilli())
.withEndTime(lastDateTimestamp.toEpochMilli());

FilterLogEventsResult response = logsClient.filterLogEvents(request);

List<FilteredLogEvent> logEvents = response.getEvents();


can you post your java code?

@AxB Hey I edited my post.

this seems similar to your question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72598027/aws-cloudwatch-logs-search-by-string-using-java.

yes I've used wrong code, I need to create this StartQueryResult with queryString...thanks for your help!
